# How to find ControlTemplate-Generated Element - FindName() excluded

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an elaborate custom control that changes the way it analyzes its content depending on the Type of control created by its ContentTemplate. I cannot depend on names being given in the template(usage by others intended), so Template.FindName won't work as in this example:
[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-find-controltemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). I havn't found a usable answer in my searches, as all results point back to the solution in the linked example. Using a VisualTreehelper would imply knowing what the template holds, so that's not the idea.

With this ContentTemplate as an Example, I need to get hold of the instance of ListBox.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyKey">
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: "*Using a VisualTreehelper would imply knowing what the template holds*" - why that? You would simply take the direct visual child of the ContentPresenter of the control.

Comment: It is hacky solution, but sometimes in order to find Controls nested deep down in the Templates of other Controls, one can use `Loaded` event of that Control (ListBox in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the nudge from a comment on the question combined with [this Post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109876/UserControl-Control-How-to-Get-a-Reference-to-an-E), I managed to Solve the Problem:

The direct visual child of the ContentPresenter being the first child in turn of the ContentControl was what I was looking for.

I was overriding OnApplytemplate to achieve my goal, and as the [Post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109876/UserControl-Control-How-to-Get-a-Reference-to-an-E) shows, for reasons not obvious to me, the ContentPresenter has to have its Template applied in turn, otherwise it remains empty.

ContentTemplate.LoadContent() is also useful, but delivers a different instance, so its only useful if you're after the Type.